# Facebook Ads API Offiline Access

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, facebook-ads-api

Offline access for the Facebook API was removed a while ago, however, on the page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal, It says:

> Ads APIs are special cased to allow collection of statistics offline. PMD partners should use server-side OAuth flow in order to receive a non-expiring token rather than a token that has longer expiration time.

I've been approved for Ads API Standard Access, but I still receive expirations on my OAuth tokens. Do I need to also become a PMD?

How can I get a non expiring token?

I've tried emailing adsapi@fb.com several times with these questions, but haven't received a response.

Comment: With a while ago I assume you mean 3 years. What type of access tokens are we talking about and what are you using them for?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @WizKid. The long lived access tokens are obtained server side using the fb_exchange_token grant type. They have an expiration date of 60 days though. I get the short lived token using the FB JS lib with a scope of 'ads_read'. I'm using them for pulling advertising account data nightly.

Comment: AFAIK only apps in Standard access level for Ads API get non expiring tokens - the document you linked is several years old and referred to a specific migration which has since passed

Comment: @Igy I have standard access but still get expiring tokens. Do I need to be a PMD as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Facebook business manager console to generate system-user access tokens that will not expire.
https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users

Comment: Anyway to do this programmatically from the API? If so, is the process documented anywhere?

Comment: Instructions for generating a system user token  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/v2.2#generate-token

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me because I have standard access of ads_read access only (because I'm doing reporting not ad buying). I get the error: Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission for ads_management. Is this behaviour expected?